# Dealing with a Hacker

Tags: criminal-law, united-kingdom, hacking

I run a small online entertainment business, recently a teenager has been hacking into our systems and causing numerous problems. After talking with him, and his refusal to cooperate, we have decided it would be best to report him to the authorities, and / or contact his parents. We have already written a report to ic3.gov and actionfraud.police.uk, however we're not sure any action will come from this.

Where else should we report this? His general vicinity is Nottingham, UK, if that helps anyone find local authorities.

Comment: You should also consider technological measures, e.g. activating stricter security settings, using stronger passwords, asking your service provider to install security updates, etc. If a local teenager can break in, it's only a matter of time before someone else out on the Internet does the same.

Answer (score 1):

First, contact the parents. A letter that he is hacking into your computer systems and that you will be forced to sue for any damages caused may work wonders. Paying someone to fix problems are obviously damages, and that will be expensive. Second, if you talked to him and he refuses to stop, obviously go straight to the police.

Comment: We aren't able to find a contact for his parents. We're still looking though. That was our first instinct. He also claims the name we have for him is not accurate, even though we can't find any evidence saying it isn't.

Comment: If the hacking exposed, but did not cause, flaws in the security, the hacker would not be liable to pay for fixing those flaws.